# Displaying catagorical data with errormargins

Tags: gnuplot

I am unable to display an x-axis with strings when using errorbars in gnuplot.

I'm trying to construct a plot where I want to compare values between discrete categories with error bars based on a standard deviation. Som example data:

```
# Catagory   Mean    SD
 static      16318.1 98.3753
 dynamic     16213.7 165.022
 guided      16275.7 71.3666
```

Based on the [documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node140.html) for error bars, I should construct the plot with the following argument: `plot datafile using xtic(1):2:3 with yerrorbars` (x, y, sd).

However, doing that seems to jumble up the axis: 
[image: Jumbled axis]

Disregarding the documentation and playing around with the order (`plot datafile using 2:3:xtic(1) with yerrorbars`) gets me almost right, but the categories are not displayed on the x-axis:
[image: no x-values]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an X coordinate.  "Column 0" returns the line number of the input data, which will serve the purpose.

```
  set offset 1,1    # leave space on either side of the plot
  plot 'foo.gp' using 0:2:3:xtic(1) with yerrorbars
```

[image]